# Добавить языковый атрибут тега html

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на трех языках, Wordpress. Подскажите, каким образом можно добавить в тег html атрибут lang. И соответственно, что бы значение атрибута lang соответствовало языковой версии страницы

Answer (score 0):

Используйте следующий фильтр:

```
function so_1171202( $output, $doctype ) {
    $locale = 'ru-RU';
    $output = preg_replace( '/lang="(.+)"/i', 'lang="' . $locale . '"', $output );

    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'so_1171202', 10, 2 );
```

Вместо `ru-RU` поставьте нужный вам язык.

А вообще-то, все плагины мультиязычности делают это.